# Extending CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider to not cache some DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, metadata, modelmetadata

I'm trying to extend `CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` to not cache Custom `ValidationAttribute`.
How can i achieve this? I tried looking in aspnetwebstack, but it is too complicated to get answer; what do i need to override, as protected override

```
protected override CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadata CreateMetadataFromPrototype(
            CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadata prototype,
            Func<object> modelAccessor)
```

and

```
protected override CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadata CreateMetadataPrototype(
            IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
            Type containerType,
            Type modelType,
            string propertyName)
```

And `CachedAssociatedMetadataProvider<TModelMetadata>` method

```
protected sealed override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
```

is sealed. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that client validations were not updated due to initialization of properties in constructor. So I moved property loading into

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
{
    var userSettings = ServiceLocator.Resolve<UserSettings>();
    if (userSettings != null)
    {
        // this was the required field to update
        this.StringLengthAttribute.MinimumLength = userSettings.MinRequiredPasswordLength;
    }

    yield return new ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule(this.ErrorMessage, this.StringLengthAttribute.MinimumLength, this.StringLengthAttribute.MaximumLength);
}
```